# Probability distribution problem - Network of friends

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A country has $4$ residents in a village and countably infinite residents
>   in its capital. In this country, a resident from the capital has $X$ friends in
>    his network, where $X$ is zipf-distributed with parameter $4$. We also know
>   that this resident doesn't have any friends from the capital, if not all residents of the
>   village are his friends. What is the probability that he will have at least one friend
>   from the capital?

I'm having some trouble while trying to apply the Zifp-distribution $(\dfrac{k^{-a}}{\sum_{k = 1}^\infty {k^{-a}}})$ to this problem.

I know that $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty {k^{-4} = \dfrac{\pi^4}{90}}$, so my idea was to calculate the probability of all $4$ villagers being his friends and subtracting this from $1$. Is this the correct approach?

How can I make use of the information that the resident doesn't have any friends from the capital, if at least one resident of the village is not his friend? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As for a recent other post (*by you? by someone else?*) that was just deleted attempting to think about binomial distributions and such as it relates to this problem... that seemed like the wrong approach entirely.  Here, the problem reads to me that our person has at least one friend in the capital if and only if $X\geq 5$ and that $X$ has no friends in the capital if and only if $X\leq 4$.  Noting that $X$ is zipf distributed should give you all the information you need to continue.

Comment: So, $Pr(X\geq 5) = 1 - Pr(X\leq 4) = 1 - \frac{1^{-4}}{\zeta(4)}-\frac{2^{-4}}{\zeta(4)}-\frac{3^{-4}}{\zeta(4)}-\frac{4^{-4}}{\zeta(4)}$.  (*Note: $X$ being zipf distributed implies $Pr(X=0)=0$*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $F_n$ the event of the person from the capital having $n$ friends. From your Text it follows that $P(F_0),...P(F_4) = P(V^0_0),...P(V^0_4)$ where $V_n^0$ denotes the event of having $n$ friends in the village and $0$ friends in the capital, because a person cannot have friends in the capital if not having 4 friends in the village.

As you guessed in some sense, the probability of having at least one friend in the capital is $1$ minus the probability of having $0$ friends in the capital.

This is $1- ( P(F_0) + P(F_1) + P(F_2) + P(F_3) +  P(F_4))$